# Segmentation fault when testing migrated library from qt4 to qt5

Tags: c++, qt, dll, segmentation-fault, migration

I am testing this library but I am getting a segmentation fault whenever it reachs a certain line (the commented one below). This issue comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539820/disassembler-failed-cannot-access-memory-at-address-0x773dfff9-qt-debugging) - tldr the same problem on a much bigger project, so I decided to test the libraries separatedly and apparently this is what fails. This code works on a co-worker's 32bits machine using Qt4 (he handed me the code). I migrated it to Qt5 and compiled with a 32bit compiler and I am getting the segmentation fault. If I comment the offending line and the two below it the program runs (although its just an empty window).
What could be happening?

```
#include "qenctest.h"

#include <QLibrary>
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>

typedef void (*encRefresh)(QPainter*);
encRefresh enc_refresh = NULL;

typedef void (*encResize)(QSize);
encResize enc_resize = NULL;

typedef QENCSignaler* (*encInit)(QString);
typedef void (*encOpenFile)(QString);

QENCTest::QENCTest(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QLibrary _qenc("qenc");
    encInit enc_init;
    encOpenFile enc_openFile;

    enc_init = (encInit) _qenc.resolve("init"); // I checked and it does load the library and the symbol succesfully
    enc_openFile = (encOpenFile) _qenc.resolve("openFile");
    enc_resize = (encResize) _qenc.resolve("resize");
    enc_refresh = (encRefresh) _qenc.resolve("refresh");

    QString path = "encfg";
    QENCSignaler* qencSignaler = enc_init(path); // Throws segfault here

    connect(qencSignaler, SIGNAL(newChart(Chart*)), this, SLOT(qencNewChart(Chart*)));
    connect(qencSignaler, SIGNAL(startReadChart(char*)), this, SLOT(qencStartReadChart(char*)));

    enc_openFile("PL2BAPOL.000");

    int _s = 0;
}
```

Debug info:
[image]

PS: What does it mean that some locals & expressions are in red?

**EDIT**

Alright, the only major changes I had to make in the library code were these:

```
AttributeSet::iterator vItPOI = attributes.at(i).find("POI");
        if (vItPOI == attributes.at(i).end()) continue;
        AttributeSet::iterator vItPOI0 = attributes.at(i).find("POI0");
        if (vItPOI0 == attributes.at(i).end()) continue;
        if (vItPOI -> getStringValue() == "Bankowoæ" &&
            selectedPOI & POI_BANKING) {

            if (vItPOI0 -> getStringValue() == "Placówka banku") {

                drawSymbol(painter, x, y, POI_BANKING);
            }
        }
```

To this (there are more ifs but this illustrates it properly)

```
ShapeAttribute vItPOI = attributes.at(i).find("POI").value();
        if (attributes.at(i).find("POI") == attributes.at(i).end()) continue;
        ShapeAttribute vItPOI0 = attributes.at(i).find("POI0").value();
        if (attributes.at(i).find("POI0") == attributes.at(i).end()) continue;
        if (vItPOI . getStringValue() == "Bankowo��" &&
            selectedPOI & POI_BANKING) {

            if (vItPOI0 . getStringValue() == "Plac�wka banku") {

                drawSymbol(painter, x, y, POI_BANKING);
            }
        }
```

In theory it should be the same shouldnt it? Although I do find strange that in the first snippet it uses -> instead of . when its not a pointer. I had to change it to that because I was getting these errors:

```
                          ^
..\qenc\ShapeLandPOI.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ShapeLandPOI::draw(QPainter*)':
..\qenc\ShapeLandPOI.cpp:74:62: error: conversion from 'QMap<QString, ShapeAttribute>::const_iterator' to non-scalar type 'QMap<QString, ShapeAttribute>::iterator' requested
   AttributeSet::iterator vItPOI = attributes.at(i).find("POI");
                                                              ^
..\qenc\ShapeLandPOI.cpp:76:64: error: conversion from 'QMap<QString, ShapeAttribute>::const_iterator' to non-scalar type 'QMap<QString, ShapeAttribute>::iterator' requested
   AttributeSet::iterator vItPOI0 = attributes.at(i).find("POI0");
                                                                ^
```

Comment: and can you step into the library code?

Comment: @ratchetfreak No sir, if I try to do it I get disassembled code, the furthest I can get is the level 4 shown above

Comment: disassembled code is fine it means that it is the library that is responsible for error not your loading code

Comment: @ratchetfreak The thing is I was handed the code from the library and  migrated it from Qt4 to Qt5, I built it in release mode and used the same compiler as this app. Perhaps I should carefully migrate it again?

Comment: You should probably rebuild a debug version of the library, and try to debug it as the fault seems to be there. It might contain some undefined behavior that appeared to work with Qt4 but doesn't any more.

Comment: If you check the first one again you will see that `vItPOI0` is an iterator, and those are accessed as pointers. And the compiler errors would be easily fixable: Use `AttributeSet::const_iterator` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your changed code you have the line

```
ShapeAttribute vItPOI0 = attributes.at(i).find("POI0").value();
```

But if `"POI0"` is not found the `find` function would return `end` which is an iterator pointing to *beyond* the collection, and so it's `value` function would be causing [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

As for the errors it seems that the `QMap` object is constant, and so you can't get non-const iterators. Just change to use `AttributeSet::const_iterator` instead and you can use the original function otherwise unmodified. This will probably fix your crashes, as then you don't have the risk of undefined behavior as described above.

Comment: I still got problems but that definetly was great part of the issue, and I have managed to locate better the issue, thankyou.